# Degrees of irreducible characters of an extension of $A_5$ by an elementary abelian 5- group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I'm reading a recent paper of G. Navarro, *[The set of character degrees of a finite group does not determine its solvability](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiHg-XpsPTJAhVCUBoKHdvZCsMQFggwMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Fproc%2F2015-143-03%2FS0002-9939-2014-12321-5%2FS0002-9939-2014-12321-5.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGeXUWslt2Ieo79SCF423OvLdE0aA)*, in which he construct two finite groups $H$ and $G$ with $cd(G)=cd(H)$ such that $G$ is solvable and $H$ is nonsolvable.

In the nonsolvable case, the character degrees are claimed without referring to GAP or ATLAS etc.
[image]

I know that {1,3,4,5}$\subset cd(H)$, since $A_5$ is a qoutient of $H$. Also by Ito theorem, for each $\theta \in Irr(H)$ we have $\theta(1) \mid 60$ since there exists a normal abelian subgroup of order $5^4$ in $H$. But I can't go further. So my question is that

```
How can we compute degrees of irreducible characters of the group $H$
just with the information mentioned in the above paragraph?
```

Comment: The fact that the author states the result with no explanation suggests that he expects readers to check it by computer, which is straightforward. There is a unique perfect group of  order $|H|$, which can be accessed in GAP or Magma from the database of perfect groups. It might be possible for an expert to do it by hand, but  that would require some knowledge of the group structure. For example,  $H$ has orbits of lengths 1,5,10.12,15,20,30 and 60 on the characters of the normal subgroup of order $5^4$ and I can infer the existence of characters of $H$ of degrees 12,15,20,30,60 (but not 10).

Comment: @DerekHolt    Aha! If I'm not mistaken, If there exists an orbit of size $k$ in the action of $H$ on  irreducible characters of normal subgroup of order $5^4$, and one of the characters in that orbit is extendable to its inertia group, then we can deduce that $H$ has an irreducible character of degree $k$.  But how did you know the orbit sizes of the action? I'd be grateful if you could explain about it more or refer me to a source about it.

Comment: The problem is that I calculated the orbits on a computer. This is an action on the $624$ nonzero vectors of a vector space of order $625$, so it could be done by hand, but that would be very tedious. I can't think of any other way of doing this, but I am not an expert on character theory!

Comment: @DerekHolt I used $\texttt{DisplayInformationPerfectGroups(37500, 1)}$ to get some information about this group in $\texttt{GAP}$. But I still don't know how to compute the orbits. Could you please guide me how to obtain the orbit lengths in $\texttt{GAP}$?

Comment: I am sorry but I am not going to offer to help you with GAP calculations. You could try the GAP Forum.

Comment: @DerekHolt OK! anyway thank you for your comments.